# Delphi Indy idHTTP causes Mac app to quit

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-10.4-sydney

Dropping an idHTTP component on a Delphi 10.4.1 MacOS project and having it Get() a file causes the app to quit.

I'm not talking about an unhandled exception. MacOS 10.15.6 kills the app with this complaint in the crash report:

```
Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
/usr/lib/libcrypto.dylib
abort() called
Invalid dylib load. Clients should not load the unversioned libcrypto dylib as it does not have a stable ABI.
```

Here is the code.  Get() must be passed an actual file. (If the Get() results in a 404, then the proper exception is raised.)

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Stream: TMemoryStream;

begin
  Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;

  IdHTTP1.Get('https://www.bookup.com/cowupdates/build113.txt', Stream);

  // app crashes on Mac
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is self-explanatory. Indy is trying to load the *unversioned* `libcrypto.dylib` file (for OpenSSL), and apparently your OSX system does not like that.

To avoid that, you can call `IdOpenSSLSetCanLoadSymLinks(False)` at program startup.  See [Changes for how OpenSSL is loaded on *Nix platforms](https://www.indyproject.org/2018/05/04/changes-for-how-openssl-is-loaded-on-nix-platforms/) on Indy's website for more details. Then, just make sure there is a version of OpenSSL 1.0.2 or earlier installed on the system, or at least in your app's folder.

There is currently an open [pull request](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/pull/299) to add OpenSSL 1.1.x support to Indy, but I don't know if it supports OSX. You could try it and see.

Comment: Thanks, Remy. I am flattered that you think the error message is self-explanatory... to me. :) I know so very little about Indy or the internet. I'm just using the component for the first time.